# How to transpose data when values appears different number of times?

Tags: excel, excel-formula, transpose

I'd like to transpose a data that is in 2 columns (A:B). for example in below input, values A,B,C and D in column A appears 3 times each of them.

With this input (input 1) I use this formula and get the transposition correctly like the image below:

```
=INDEX($B$1:$B$12,4*ROWS(D$2:D2)+COLUMNS($D2:D2)-4)
```

INPUT1

```
+---+----+
| A |  2 |
+---+----+
| B |  3 |
+---+----+
| C |  4 |
+---+----+
| D |  1 |
+---+----+
| A |  6 |
+---+----+
| B | 12 |
+---+----+
| C |  4 |
+---+----+
| D | 76 |
+---+----+
| A |  1 |
+---+----+
| B |  2 |
+---+----+
| C | 37 |
+---+----+
| D |  9 |
+---+----+
```

[image]

But if input change (input2) in such way that A, B appears less times than C and D, my output is incorrect.

INPUT2

```
+---+----+
| A |  2 |
+---+----+
| B |  3 |
+---+----+
| C |  4 |
+---+----+
| D |  1 |
+---+----+
| C |  4 |
+---+----+
| D | 76 |
+---+----+
| C | 37 |
+---+----+
| D |  9 |
+---+----+
| A | 47 |
+---+----+
| B |  2 |
+---+----+
| C | 37 |
+---+----+
| D |  9 |
+---+----+
```

I show in image below the incorrect output and expected output.
[image]

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: Will there be a situation where only one letter will exist for a data set e.g. only A, B, C,D? What defines end of the set each time?

Comment: The end of the set would be letter D. But see it like blocks from A to D followed by one or more "incomplete" blocks from C to D, then appears again a complete block from A to D and so on. I hope make sense

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a fairly simple approach based on counting how many cells have been filled in so far:

```
=IF(INDEX($A:$A,COUNT($D$1:$G1)+COUNT($C2:C2)+1)=D$1,
INDEX($B:$B,COUNT($D$1:$G1)+COUNT($C2:C2)+1),"")
```

copied down and across starting from D2. Assumes that a blank column is available in column C.

[image]

If you want to make it more dynamic but also want it to work for earlier versions of Excel than Microsoft 365, it gets a bit ugly unfortunately. You can use a conventional way of listing out the unique values in column A in alphabetical order to get the headers:

```
=IFERROR(INDEX($A:$A, MATCH(SMALL(IF((COUNTIF(C$1:$C1, $A$1:INDEX($A:$A,COUNTA($A:$A)))=0), COUNTIF($A$1:INDEX($A:$A,COUNTA($A:$A)), "<"&$A$1:INDEX($A:$A,COUNTA($A:$A))), ""), 1), COUNTIF($A$1:INDEX($A:$A,COUNTA($A:$A)), "<"&$A$1:INDEX($A:$A,COUNTA($A:$A))), 0)),"")
```

adapted from [this](https://www.get-digital-help.com/create-a-unique-alphabetically-sorted-list-extracted-from-a-column/), pulled across as required (say, to column Z).

Then a slight modification to the main formula to avoid zeroes appearing under the blank headers:

```
=IF(AND(INDEX($A:$A,COUNT($D$1:$Z1)+COUNT($C2:C2)+1)=D$1,D$1<>""),
INDEX($B:$B,COUNT($D$1:$Z1)+COUNT($C2:C2)+1),"")
```

Copied down and across as far as column Z.

[image]

Comment: Thanks Tom for your help and time. It works with the input I shown. But is there a way to make the formula more general?. I mean, to work with more values. For example my actual data have 10 different values in column A(let say from Val1 to Val10) in column A. In this question I only show a small representative pattern sample to make it simple to understand. You can see it like blocks from Val1 to Val10 followed by one or more "incomplete" blocks from Val6 to Val10, then appears again a complete block from Val1 to Val10 and so on. I hope make sense

Comment: Well in Microsoft 365 you could use Unique and Transpose to get the column headers, then you'd have to make the ranges (like $D$1:$G$1) dynamic. I think it could be done - will have a look at it later. Another question is whether it could be done with a spill formula - that seems harder.

Comment: I understand spill formula only are available in office 365. If is easy for you is fine, even I'll need to use this in machines with Excel 2016 too.